# When to add s to a noun

Tags: grammar

I would like to know when should I use s with a noun I tried to find this out but I couldn't.

1. 85 location
2. 85 locations

and why?

Answer (score 2):

Adding "s" (or sometimes "es" if the noun ends with certain letters, like x or s) to a noun makes it **plural**, meaning there is more than one. This is true for most nouns, though some common nouns have plurals that are formed differently.

**Examples of typical singular/plural formations:**

- One location, two location*s*, eighty-five location*s*.
- One bus, two bus*es*, eighty-five bus*es*.
- One box, two box*es*, eighty-five box*es*.